# types of decoder for xml

Tags: android

I am not getting the decoder for the following xml. I am using utf-8 but not getting the the following content

```
<ArrayOfEventsFeed xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TheDistrictt.Model" 
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <EventsFeed z:Id="i1" 
        xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
        <EntityKey i:nil="true" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" 
            xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data"/>
        <Description>RoxLousiana kitchen brings the big easy to santana row with a big new 
            orleans-style bash to clebrate Mardi Gras.</Description>
        <EndDate>2010-02-21T10:06:00</EndDate>
        <EventId>1</EventId>
        <Link>www.sumasoftware.com</Link>
        <StartDate>2010-02-16T05:00:00</StartDate>
        <StoreAddress>Roux Lousiana Kitchen at Santana row:3055 Olin Avenve</StoreAddress>
        <StoreLogo>http://thedistrict.testshell.net/Images/event1.jpg</StoreLogo>
        <StorePhone>4096421234</StorePhone>
        <StoreUrl>www.sumasoftware.com</StoreUrl>
        <Title>Roux Louisiana Kitchen</Title>
    </EventsFeed>
    <EventsFeed z:Id="i2" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
        <EntityKey i:nil="true" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" 
            xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data"/>
        <Description>The former's Market brings the Big eay to Santarow with a big new
            orleans style bash to clebrate mardigras.</Description>
        <EndDate>2010-03-30T09:00:00</EndDate>
        <EventId>2</EventId>
        <Link>www.stellentsoft.com</Link>
        <StartDate>2010-03-15T10:00:00</StartDate>
        <StoreAddress>1140 Olsen Drive San jose, CA 95128</StoreAddress>
        <StoreLogo>http://thedistrict.testshell.net/Images/event2.jpg</StoreLogo>
        <StorePhone>8096425240</StorePhone>
        <StoreUrl>www.stellentsoft.com</StoreUrl>
        <Title>Former's Market</Title>
    </EventsFeed>
    <EventsFeed z:Id="i3" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
        <EntityKey i:nil="true" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" 
            xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data"/>
        <Description>New</Description>
        <EndDate>2010-11-30T00:00:00</EndDate>
        <EventId>5</EventId>
        <Link>www.event.com</Link>
        <StartDate>2010-11-20T00:00:00</StartDate>
        <StoreAddress>45-43rfdssdf</StoreAddress>
        <StoreLogo>http://thedistrict.testshell.net/Images/image002.jpg</StoreLogo>
        <StorePhone>8096425242</StorePhone>
        <StoreUrl>www.cellgateusa.com</StoreUrl>
        <Title>NewEventFortesting</Title>
    </EventsFeed>
</ArrayOfEventsFeed>
```

thanks.

Comment: What specifically is your question?

Comment: I am getting this content from web services. url is http://thedistrict.testshell.net/GetEventsFeed. When displaying the content am i am getting like this . I want to parse the xml. thanks

Comment: I am giving the content getting in logcat.05-11 20:29:51.642: ERROR/data(541): Ã¯Â»Â¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
05-11 20:29:51.642

Comment: The question should just be, "How do I parse XML in the Android framework", and googling that question will give you better results than asking on StackOverflow.  The actual XML data is irrelevant to the question

Comment: 05-11 20:29:51.642: ERROR/data(541): Ã¯Â»Â¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
05-11 20:29:51.642

Comment: in my xml file there is no there is no start and end tag of xml .is it responsible for wrong data receving over wire.

Comment: when I clicked your link, there was no xml declaration at the top...therefore, invalid xml.  What library are you using to parse this?